# How to track traffic from and to specific page

Tags: google-analytics, traffic

I am looking for how to track traffic from and to a specifix external page.

So I want to know how many people from example1233412.com are coming to a page on my website, as well as how many people from my site are going to example1233412.com

How can I set this up?

I have looked under the categories but am unsure how to proceed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**For incoming traffic you can do it two ways:**

1. Check your Acquisition > Referrals report
2. Use a campaign URL if you control those external pages so they show up on Acquisition > Campaigns report

**For outbound traffic, you'll need an event listener.**

You can use JavaScript (or jQuery if you prefer) to listen for `<a>` tags with `href` that contains `example1233412.com` specifically, or you could track all outbound links where `href` does not match your hostname or listen for a `rel=external`. There are many ways to do this.

The other thing to think about is that outbound link tracking has been tricky in the past- when someone leaves your site, typically JavaScript stops executing. I personally have had luck with tracking these without setting up some kind of callback (BTW: callbacks for `window.location.href` are bad UX because it prevents users from controlling their tabs!), but you can also look into the new [Beacon transport mechanism](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/sending-hits) of sending hits to Google Analytics (which is useful in this exact situation).